# glutPostRedisplay() not always being called?

Tags: c, opengl, glut, freeglut

I have a program in which a coloured cube is displayed with OpenGL. I am using freeglut to display the OpenGL instance. The program is supposed to allow the user to rotate the cube with their mouse while they are holding their left mouse button down. After each mouse movement the cursor is supposed to be centered in the window then glutPostRedisplay(); is meant to be called only it gets called a few times then stops getting called until you release the left mouse button.

my_cube.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Function Prototypes
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void display();
void specialKeys();

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Global Variables
// ----------------------------------------------------------
double rotate_y=0; 
double rotate_x=0;
float deltaAngleX = 0.0f;
float deltaAngleY = 0.0f;
int xOrigin = -1;
int yOrigin = -1;
int MSAA;
int MouseState = 0;
void enableMultisample(int msaa){
    if(msaa)
    {
        glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
        glHint(GL_MULTISAMPLE_FILTER_HINT_NV, GL_NICEST);

        //detect current settings
        GLint iMultiSample = 0;
        GLint iNumSamples = 0;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, &iMultiSample);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_SAMPLES, &iNumSamples);
        //printf("MSAA on, GL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS = %d, GL_SAMPLES = %d\n", iMultiSample, iNumSamples);
    }
    else
    {
        glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
        //printf("MSAA off\n");
    }
}


void mouseButton(int button, int state, int x, int y) {

    // only start motion if the left button is pressed
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {

        // when the button is released
        if (state == GLUT_UP) {
            //rotate_x += deltaAngleX;
            //rotate_y += deltaAngleY;
            xOrigin = -1;
            yOrigin = -1;
            MouseState = 0;
        }
        else  {// state = GLUT_DOWN
            xOrigin = x;
            yOrigin = y;
            MouseState = 1;
        }
    }
}
void mouseMove(int x, int y) {
    // this will only be true when the left button is down
    if (xOrigin >= 0) {
        int midWindowX = 1280 / 2;
        int midWindowY = 720 / 2;

        rotate_y -= (x - midWindowX) / 10.0f;
        rotate_x += (y - midWindowY) / 10.0f;
        glutWarpPointer(midWindowX, midWindowY);

        //glutPostRedisplay();

        printf("Rotate_X = %lf   :   Rotate_Y = %lf   :   Mouse_X = %d   :    Mouse_Y = %d\n", rotate_x, rotate_y, x, y);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// display() Callback function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void display(){

    //  Clear screen and Z-buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Reset transformations
    //
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0f, (1280.0f/720.0f), 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    enableMultisample(MSAA);

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -4);
    glRotatef(180, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    // Rotate when user changes rotate_x and rotate_y
    glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );

    // Reset rotations
    if(rotate_x == 360.0f || rotate_x > 360.0f || rotate_x == -360 || rotate_x < -360) rotate_x = 0.0f;
    if(rotate_y == 360.0f || rotate_y > 360.0f || rotate_y == -360 || rotate_y < -360) rotate_y = 0.0f;

    //Multi-colored side - FRONT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );      // P4 is green
    glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );      // P3 is blue
    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );      // P2 is purple
    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );      // P1 is red

    glEnd();

    // White side - BACK
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(   1.0,  1.0, 1.0 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Purple side - RIGHT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(  1.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Green side - LEFT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(   0.0,  1.0,  0.0 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Blue side - TOP
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(   0.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Red side - BOTTOM
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(   1.0,  0.0,  0.0 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();

}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// specialKeys() Callback Function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void specialKeys( int key, int x, int y ) {
    if(!MouseState){ 
        //  Right arrow - increase rotation by 5 degree
        if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
            rotate_y -= 5;

        //  Left arrow - decrease rotation by 5 degree
        else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
            rotate_y += 5;

        else if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
            rotate_x -= 5;

        else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
            rotate_x += 5;

        //  Request display update
        glutPostRedisplay();
    } 
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// main() function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    for(int i; i<argc; i++){
        char *arg;
        arg = argv[i];
        const char msaaArg[4] = "MSAA";
        char *ret;

        ret = strstr(arg, msaaArg);

        if(ret != NULL){
            MSAA = (intptr_t)argv[i+1];
        }
    }

    //  Initialize GLUT and process user parameters
    glutInit(&argc,argv);

    //  Set Initial Size of window
    glutInitWindowSize(1280, 720);

    // Enable Multisampling
    glutSetOption(GLUT_MULTISAMPLE, 8);

    //  Request double buffered true color window with Z-buffer
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);

    // Create window
    glewInit();
    glutCreateWindow("");

    // Get OpenGL Version
    printf("Using OpenGL Version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION)); 
    char title[150];
    const char* temp;
    strcpy(title, "Awesome Cube [OpenGL Version ");
    strcat(title, glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    temp = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    strcat(title, "]");
    glutSetWindowTitle(title);

    //  Enable Z-buffer depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Enable Backface Culling
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); 

    // Move mouse to the middle of the screen
    glutWarpPointer(1280/2, 720/2);

    // Callback functions
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);
    glutMouseFunc(mouseButton);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMove); 
    //  Pass control to GLUT for events
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I didn't consider it necessary to use the computers resources all the time. I only wanted to render the image when it was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glutWarpPointer()` generates a new mouse motion callback; set a flag and ignore warp-generated motion callbacks:

```
bool warped = false;
void mouseMove( int x, int y )
{
    if( warped )
    {
        warped = false;
        return;
    }

    // this will only be true when the left button is down
    if( xOrigin >= 0 )
    {
        int midWindowX = 1280 / 2;
        int midWindowY = 720 / 2;

        rotate_y -= ( x - midWindowX ) / 10.0f;
        rotate_x += ( y - midWindowY ) / 10.0f;

        warped = true;
        glutWarpPointer( midWindowX, midWindowY );

        printf( "Rotate_X = %lf   :   Rotate_Y = %lf   :   Mouse_X = %d   :    Mouse_Y = %d\n", rotate_x, rotate_y, x, y );
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}
```

All together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Function Prototypes
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void display();
void specialKeys();

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Global Variables
// ----------------------------------------------------------
double rotate_y = 0;
double rotate_x = 0;
float deltaAngleX = 0.0f;
float deltaAngleY = 0.0f;
int xOrigin = -1;
int yOrigin = -1;
int MouseState = 0;

void mouseButton( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    // only start motion if the left button is pressed
    if( button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON )
    {
        // when the button is released
        if( state == GLUT_UP )
        {
            //rotate_x += deltaAngleX;
            //rotate_y += deltaAngleY;
            xOrigin = -1;
            yOrigin = -1;
            MouseState = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // state = GLUT_DOWN
            xOrigin = x;
            yOrigin = y;
            MouseState = 1;
        }
    }
}

bool warped = false;
void mouseMove( int x, int y )
{
    if( warped )
    {
        warped = false;
        return;
    }

    // this will only be true when the left button is down
    if( xOrigin >= 0 )
    {
        int midWindowX = 1280 / 2;
        int midWindowY = 720 / 2;

        rotate_y -= ( x - midWindowX ) / 10.0f;
        rotate_x += ( y - midWindowY ) / 10.0f;

        warped = true;
        glutWarpPointer( midWindowX, midWindowY );

        printf( "Rotate_X = %lf   :   Rotate_Y = %lf   :   Mouse_X = %d   :    Mouse_Y = %d\n", rotate_x, rotate_y, x, y );
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// display() Callback function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void display()
{
    //  Clear screen and Z-buffer
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Reset transformations
    //
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 60.0f, ( 1280.0f / 720.0f ), 0.1f, 100.0f );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -4 );
    glRotatef( 180, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

    // Rotate when user changes rotate_x and rotate_y
    glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );

    // Reset rotations
    if( rotate_x == 360.0f || rotate_x > 360.0f || rotate_x == -360 || rotate_x < -360 ) rotate_x = 0.0f;
    if( rotate_y == 360.0f || rotate_y > 360.0f || rotate_y == -360 || rotate_y < -360 ) rotate_y = 0.0f;

    //Multi-colored side - FRONT
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );

    glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );      // P4 is green
    glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.5, 0.5, -0.5 );      // P3 is blue
    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, -0.5 );      // P2 is purple
    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );      // P1 is red

    glEnd();

    // White side - BACK
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    glColor3f( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Purple side - RIGHT
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Green side - LEFT
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, 0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Blue side - TOP
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, 0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Red side - BOTTOM
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// specialKeys() Callback Function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void specialKeys( int key, int x, int y )
{
    if( !MouseState )
    {
        //  Right arrow - increase rotation by 5 degree
        if( key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT )
            rotate_y -= 5;

        //  Left arrow - decrease rotation by 5 degree
        else if( key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT )
            rotate_y += 5;

        else if( key == GLUT_KEY_UP )
            rotate_x -= 5;

        else if( key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN )
            rotate_x += 5;

        //  Request display update
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// main() function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    //  Initialize GLUT and process user parameters
    glutInit( &argc, argv );

    //  Set Initial Size of window
    glutInitWindowSize( 1280, 720 );

    //  Request double buffered true color window with Z-buffer
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );

    // Create window
    glewInit();
    glutCreateWindow( "" );

    //  Enable Z-buffer depth test
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    // Enable Backface Culling
    glEnable( GL_CULL_FACE );

    // Move mouse to the middle of the screen
    glutWarpPointer( 1280 / 2, 720 / 2 );

    // Callback functions
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutSpecialFunc( specialKeys );
    glutMouseFunc( mouseButton );
    glutMotionFunc( mouseMove );
    //  Pass control to GLUT for events
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```